# Cannot start mxnet on windows using R

Tags: r, windows, mxnet

I am trying to get running mxnet but I still get this error, can you help me please ?

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mxnet’:

 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'mxnet', details:

  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)

  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/patrik/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/mxnet/libs/x64/libmxnet.dll':

LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: did you install the cpu or gpu version? btw, I followed the installation guide http://mxnet.io/get_started/install.html with no issue.

Comment: Kindly share more information about your attempts, environment, exact path you took towards the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was using not supported version of Cuda.